# How to make ajax shortcode work outside the loop

Tags: ajax, wordpress, shortcode

I am using shortcodes with attribute and content in my Wordpress posts. These shortcodes are necessary so I have to use them. I am ajaxing the index and single pages. I am having a problem with ajaxing the single posts because when I output the post content to return to the clientside the shortcodes don't work.

Any suggestions on forcing a way?

```
function ajaxsingle() {
    global $wpdb;
    $postID = $_POST[ 'postID' ];
    $post = get_post( $postID );
    $postType = get_post_type($postID);
    $slug = $post->post_name; 
    $title = get_the_title($postID);
    $thumbnailUrl = wp_get_attachment_url(get_post_thumbnail_id($postID));
    $excerpt = apply_filters('the_excerpt', get_post_field('post_excerpt', $postID));
    $sidebar = the_widget( 'post-inner-sidebar' );
    $post_content = $post->post_content;
    $imgBackground = "../wp-content/themes/webdev/img/";
    $imgBackground .= get_post_field( 'post_name', get_post($postID) );
    $imgBackground .= "_preview.jpg";

    if ($postType == "articles" || $postType == "tutorials") {

        $html = '<div id="blogWrap" style="background: linear-gradient(to right, rgba(255,255,255,0) 29%,rgba(255,255,255,0.9) 29%,rgba(255,255,255,0.9) 100%), url('.$imgBackground.'); opacity: 0;"><div id="articleHeader"><div id="headerLogo" style="background: url('.$thumbnailUrl.'), linear-gradient(to right, rgba(248,194,121,1) 0%,rgba(248,194,121,1) 100%)"></div><div id="excerptIntro"><div id="excerptInner"><h1>'.$title.'</h1><div class="leftQuotemark tutorials-leftQuotemark"></div><p>'.$excerpt.'</p><div class="rightQuotemark tutorials-rightQuotemark"></div></div></div></div><div id="blogInnerWrap"><div id="adContentWrap">'.$sidebar.'</div><div id="tutorialContent">'.$post_content.'</div></div></div></div>';

    } else if ($postType == "case-studies"){

        $html = '<div id="blogWrap" style="background: linear-gradient(to right, rgba(255,255,255,0) 29%,rgba(255,255,255,0.9) 29%,rgba(255,255,255,0.9) 100%), url('.$imgBackground.'); opacity: 0;"><div id="blogInnerWrap">'.$post_content.'</div></div></div>';

    } else if ($postType == "software") {

        $html = '<div id="blogWrap" style="background: linear-gradient(to right, rgba(255,255,255,0) 29%,rgba(255,255,255,0.9) 29%,rgba(255,255,255,0.9) 100%), url('.$imgBackground.'); opacity: 0;"><div id="softwareHeader"><div id="headerLogo" style="background-image: url('.$thumbnailUrl.'); ?>")></div><div id="excerptIntro"><h1>'.$title.'</h1><div class="leftQuotemark software-leftQuotemark"></div><p>'.$excerpt.'</p><div class="rightQuotemark software-rightQuotemark"></div></div></div><div id="blogInnerWrap">'.$post_content.'</div></div></div>';

    }

   echo $html;
   wp_die();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In your code try to search shortcode with regular expression and call [do_shortcode](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/do_shortcode/) function for each shortcode to get the result of shortcode processing and insert it into $html variable.

Comment: Yes this was my plan B. Regex string search to cut up the shortcode text and implement. I am hoping someone has another more efficient way.

Comment: Maybe try to get html of post with wp_remote_retrieve_body() and extract the conten part then, As for me, more easy way.

Answer (score 0):

Initialize `$html` with a default value or make sure that `$postType` match with some of your predefined values: `"articles"`, `"tutorials"`,  `"case-studies"`, or `"software"`.

Comment: The postType does match and I do get html sent to the front end.The problem is that wordpress doesn't allow shortcodes in an ajax enviroment. it just prints the entire shortcode on the page as text. Yet these shortcodes are crucial to the system so I have to find the best way to implement this.